# Mailchimp API growth-history method returns 0 on some months

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm successfully connecting to Mailchimp API 3.0 using PHP Curl.

When I place a call to growth-history I get a json response. It contains an object with a history property with monthly objects that contain a count of subscribers.

For example, here is the object inside the History property, for January 2018 month:

```
list_id: (string) a5908434c1
month: (string) 2018-01
existing: (integer) 0 
imports: (integer) 0 
optins: (integer) 6
```

This looks all good, with the exception that as of January 2018 I have 541 subscribers. The "existing" property of this month should reflect that but it isn't. This is also happening on at least 4 other months out of 7 that my list has records. The other 3 months correctly show the subscriber count.

Is this an expected behavior or is the API failing to return a correct existing subscriber count for each month?

I'm using the instructions given here: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/growth-history/#read-get_lists_list_id_growth_history_month

And if I make the same call on the mailchimp playground, I get the same results. Here's a screenshot of the response:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gUMulJorFGr76QsSRQoA2qGFgwJDl-PC

Am I using growth-history incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Here is mailchimp's response, in case anybody else finds themselves in the same position:

> Hi there Mauricio,
>
> Thank you for writing into MailChimp Support. Our friendly Twitter
>   team passed your information along to us and I'll be happy to help
>   investigate the /lists/{list_id}/growth-history results.
>
> Based on the provided information, I was able to run a test call to
>   your list using the /lists/{list_id}/growth-history API endpoint and
>   also received the same results. It appears that this is a known issue
>   that our developers are investigating. I have gone ahead and passed
>   your information along to them. Unfortunately I am unable to provide
>   an estimated timeframe on when we will hear back from them, however
>   once a fix is found it will be pushed along.
>
> In the mean time the stats for existing subscribers & newly opted-in
>   contacts can be found in the list by manually running segments. This
>   can be done by navigating to the Lists page > click the List Name >
>   selecting 'Create a Segment' > setting the segmentation condition
>   drop-down menus to "Date Added - is after - a specific date - the last
>   date of the previous month (12/31/17)" and "Date added - is before - a
>   specific date - the first date of the upcoming month (2/1/18)" >
>   clicking "Preview Segment."
>
> This will load the contact table to show the total number of
>   subscribed contacts in the list (541) beside the list name, as well as
>   the number of contacts which joined the list between the selected
>   dates in the segment (ex: 6 subscribers for January).
>
> I understand that this workflow may not be ideal and requires a bit
>   more work than running an API call for the data and apologize for any
>   inconvenience this may cause. If you should have any additional
>   questions, please feel free to reach back out to Support. We're always
>   happy to help as much as we can.
>
> I hope you have a wonderful day, Mauricio. Thank you, Bri